# how to handle errors from a custom validation with JOI?

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, joi

I want set a custom error message for my custom validation with JOI, but this not work

```
 field: Joi.string()
.required()
.custom((value, helper) => {
  if (!isValidField(value)) {
    return helper.message({'any.custom': 'This value is Invalid'});
  }
  return value;
}),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with this code

```
field: Joi.string()
.required()
.custom((value, helper) => {
  if (isValidField(value)) {
    return value;
  }
  return helper.message({ custom: 'This value is Invalid' });
})
```

found the answer on this link: https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2235